# When switching to job specific databases with EF5, will caching still work?

Tags: database, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-5

I'm designing a web service that returns simple query information. Using webApi & EF5. Easy.
The problem I need help solving is this.
We have **15 SQL servers** with a combined **200+ databases**. The **schemas are all the same**. Each DB is customer/case specific. So the API gets called with a case# and finds the sql server & db name from a lookup table.

I know how to set the dbContext to a specific connection string. So telling EF5 what to connect to is easy enough. 
It seems I will be **losing any connection caching capabilities** by having to switch DB's with every call.

On a busy day, we'll have 10-60 users per case #, and about 20 cases a day. (read **20 unique DB connections** a day)

Should I create my own connection cache inside my WebAPI? As simple as a List of last used connections? Or will EF5 just work?